# "Индикаторная" функция для элементов массива

Tags: python, оптимизация, numpy, scipy

Я сразу с примера того, что мне нужно.

Можно ли без циклов и `map` сделать из массива `a = [3, 1, 3]` два таких массива `[[3, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0]]`? Т. е. новый массив имеет размер `(n, len(a))`, где n - это число различных элементов в `a`. При этом строчки нового массива образуются так: одинаковые элементы остаются на своих местах, а на остальных местах взамен старых ставятся нули. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Например:
на входе массив: `a = [3, 1, 2, 1, 3]`
ожидаемый результат: `[[3, 0, 0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0]]`.

Можно ли методами векторизации решить эту задачу?

Порядок получившихся строк не имеет значения. У меня практически нет идей. Допустим, я создал n нужных пустых массивов (допустим они состоят из нулей). А как дальше? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Еще есть идея использовать numpy.where, но опять таки не понятно как реализовать без циклов.

Comment: попробуйте реализовать с помощью рекурсии

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Без циклов for:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([3, 1, 2, 1, 3])
n_a=a.shape[0] # число элементов в исходном массиве 
unq=np.unique(a) 
n_unq=unq.shape[0] # число уникальных элементов
b= np.tile(a, (n_unq, 1))
c=np.tile(unq, (n_a, 1)).T
print(c*(b==c))
```

или еще вариант:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([3, 1, 2, 1, 3])
unq=np.unique(a) 
M=np.meshgrid(a, unq)
print(np.where(M[0]==M[1], M[0], 0))
```

Если массив большой, то, возможно, стоит использовать разреженные матрицы.

Comment: Красивое решение)

Answer (score 5):

Полувекторизированное решение - цикл пробегает по уникальным значениям:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([3, 1, 2, 1, 3])
unq = pd.unique(a)
res = np.zeros((len(unq), len(a)), dtype="int32")

for i,n in enumerate(unq):
    res[i][a == n] = n
```

результат:

```
In [265]: res
Out[265]:
array([[3, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```